# Creating a dockable form that stays above the task bar

Tags: c#, winforms, dock, docking

I am trying to create a news ticker and I'm looking for the best way to create a dockable form that will dock to the desktop, just above the task bar (the user can move it to dock to one of the sides or the top of the screen). What is the best way to do this in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this article [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/csdoesshell3.aspx?df=100&forumid=14729&exp=0&select=742202).  It's an older article, but since it's based off of shell programming, it should still apply for more recent versions of the framework.